# Why does the ie11 emulator have more options than edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

In the IE emulation tool, document mode has several options on IE11 but only Edge and Windows Phone on Edge.

Is there anyway to get all of the options on edge too?

Comment: While this question is completely off-topic here, I'll try to answer briefly. Think of Edge as a smaller, optimised version of IE11, it has been stripped down to the minimum to make surfing the web super fast. So it does not include all the developers' goodies are used to in other browsers

Comment: @Salketer: How is this question off-topic here? It's a question about F12. It's completely *on*-topic here. Also, your last statement isn't quite correct - other than the lack of IE emulation options the F12 tools are in fact more comprehensive in Edge than in IE.

Comment: Thanks guys, that explains it

Comment: @BoltClock I felt that the question was more asking why at first. Which can only be opinionated... Then OP asks how to get X or Y option on a software, which is also another reason to be off-topic. But meh, seems I'm the only one who voted so I'm certainly the one mistaken :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is why Microsoft Edge doesn't have options to emulate Internet Explorer, that's simply because they're two different browsers. In fact, Trident and EdgeHTML are even more different than WebKit and Blink. Compatibility issues aside (Trident isn't going to work on UWP), it simply doesn't make sense to offer IE emulation in Microsoft Edge.

If your question is why Microsoft Edge doesn't have options to emulate previous versions of EdgeHTML, that's because Edge is an evergreen browser, and Windows 10 is an evergreen OS, where support for older builds (enterprise and LTSB notwithstanding) ends much quicker in favor of pushing users to upgrade to the newest version of Windows 10. In fact, I'm surprised Edge is still offering Windows 10 Mobile emulation at this point.

Comment: Yes, and it's worth noting that even when you're testing different docmodes within IE11 you're never truly getting the IE10 experience. Why? Because IE and Edge for that matter, utilize a lot of the Windows subsystem such as DWrite and DComp and improvements/modifications made to these are not switched when you swap docmodes, solely code paths within Trident are modified. Thus, you're testing IE* on the current OS, but IE* on the older version may render completely different. This, and the technical debt, leads to a lack of desire by Microsoft to keep this feature in Edge.